# Let f(z) be an entire function such that abs(f(z))>3 for all z. Find f'(z).

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been trying to use Liouville's theorem, but it does not seem to be working right. The only thing I can think of is that f'(z) does not exist because in all of my examples and in the book there is no situation where abs(f(z)) > M, it is always less than or equal to.

Comment: Does absolute value mean modulus?  What does $f'$ mean here?

Comment: yes it does mean modulus, sorry about that. That is f prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)}$.  By the assumption, $g$ is also an entire function, and is also bounded.  Thus, $g$ is constant by Liouville's theorem.  So too is $f$ then, so $f' = 0$.

Comment: I understand that part, but it is the mod(f(Z)) > 3 that is throwing me off. It effects the problem in some way and I can not figure that out.

Comment: If you understand this part, the problem is done.  If $|f(z)| > 3$, then in particular, $f$ is not $0$ ever.  The "$3$" doesn't matter; it could be any positive number.

Comment: So then f'(z)=0 since f(z) is analytic everywhere. I'm sorry I'm just trying to fully understand this problem.

Comment: .... $f'$ is $0$ because $f$ is constant......